# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Hello stackoverflow community, I have been facing with a little problem whole week. I'm trying to launch Map activity from my Main activity, and after calling Map Activity I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: eu.tinysolutions.tinytracker, PID: 12795
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eu.tinysolutions.tinytracker/eu.tinysolutions.tinytracker.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2572)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:412)
                  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2191)
                  at eu.tinysolutions.tinytracker.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:20)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6309)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:412) 
                  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2191) 
                  at eu.tinysolutions.tinytracker.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:20) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6309) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.q.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):40)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):11)
                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):4)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.b.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):24)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):69)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):32)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12673019@12.6.73 (040300-194189626):31)
                  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:392)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.transactAndReadException(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzf.zzc(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzc(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.createDelegate(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onInflate(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1306)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3672)
                at android.support.v4.app.
```

MainActivity code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapInit();
}
public void mapInit(){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class));

}
```

MapsAcitivity is just a default android studio google maps activity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

  private GoogleMap mMap;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
  }
```

I have found out that the app brakes on MapsActivity `setContentView` line

**P.S** I've added API key to manifest file

**UPDATE**

sorry, I've forgotten to add layout files

Here is the activity_maps layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

Comment: Add you layout file. There is a problem with you MapFragment.

Comment: can u share layout file.

Comment: Sorry, edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its there in the logs

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml`

add your API key in manifest file

e.g.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    .
    .
    <application
          .  
          <meta-data
                 android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                 android:value="YOUR API KEY HERE" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did a silly mistake :D at android:name="....API_KEY" I've entered my KEY, thats why the app was crashing. That silly mistake cost me 1 week of work :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, because you are using a fragment without a container view.

You can read about it from the [Building a Flexible UI documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui#AddAtRuntime):

> An important rule when dealing with fragments—especially when adding
>   fragments at runtime—is that your activity layout must include a
>   container View in which you can insert the fragment.

And from this [Fragment documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments):

> When you add a fragment as a part of your activity layout, it lives in
>   a **ViewGroup** inside the activity's view hierarchy and the fragment
>   defines its own view layout. You can insert a fragment into your
>   activity layout by declaring the fragment in the activity's layout
>   file, as a  element, or from your application code by adding
>   it to an existing **ViewGroup**

So, add a root layout to your xml by changing your `activity_maps` layout to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" >

      <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Remember to use `class` instead of `android:name` attribute.